How to get the zip code using the new Google map Places API Autocomplete (New)?
I'm trying to get a list of addresses from USA with autocomplete search with the help of the new Google maps places api (Autocomplete endpoint).
This is what I tried to do to get it but it's not include the zip code:
const fetchPlaces = async (inputValue: string) => {
    if (!inputValue) return;

    const response = await fetch(
      `https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:autocomplete`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-Goog-Api-Key": process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_API_KEY || "",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          input: inputValue,
          includedRegionCodes: ["us"],
        }),
      }
    );
    return await response.json();
  };

What I'm missing here? I didn't find anything about the zip code on the docs.

From the examples within the documation it seems like that they don't return a zip code. - You need to request them based on the placeId using the places/{id} API Endpoint.

Autocomplete predictions won't include the ZIP code until the input contains at least one digit that matches the ZIP code, see https://issuetracker.google.com/73730686
